# Conexão do apache entre máquinas de mesma rede

Tags: php, wamp

Bom, utilizando o Wamp Server, estou tentando fazer com que uma outra máquina também tenha o acesso as páginas colocadas na pasta C:/wamp/www/Site, por exemplo. Até agora, só consegui fazer com que a outra máquina abra o ipdaminhamaquina/phppgadmin. Estou usando a porta 80 do computador no apache e já coloquei Allow from all no arquivo do apache. Alguém pode dar alguma ajuda?